# how to show file counter using file_download

Tags: views, 8, blocks

This is a beginner question, in [file_download](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_download) module. I have installed it and then I followed Install Instructions. But I couldn't figure out how to show the counter or statistics_popular_block, I tried to create a new view but didn't get any thing. I am new to views.

When I look to the source code I can see things such like:

```
src
  FileDownloadSettingsForm.php
  Plugin
     Block
         FileDownloadPopularBlock.php
     views
         field
             FileDownloadCounterTimestamp.php
             FileDownloadNumeric.php
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

The module's project page gives these instructions:

1. Download to modules directory
2. Enable module
3. Apply formatter to any file or image field
4. Apply settings for title, currently either filename or nothing

Did you apply the formatter?  To apply the formatter, you need to go to "Manage field display" for your content type, choose the image/file field, and then change the formatter.

Comment: I've already followed these instructions but the counter itself doesn't show up. The link to the file changed to "http://localhost/test/drupal/docroot/en/file-download/download/public/15"